# How add method get by ID?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have general class.
I need create method get seingleOrDefault by ID?

How to do this?

```
public T GetByID(int id)
{
    _entities.Set<T>().Single(x => x.);
}
```

general class:

```
   public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> : IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
    {

        private C _entities = new C();
        public C Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in a generic fashion, you need to add a generic constraint on `T`.

Something like

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : class, IEntity
    where C : DbContext, new()
{
    public T GetByID(int id)
    {
        _entities.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `DbContext` then method `Set<T>()` returns [`DbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) instead of [`ObjectSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382816.aspx). `DbSet<T>` has method [`DbSet<T>.Find(params object[] keyValues)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which does exactly what you are trying to implement:

> This method uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the
>   context. If the entity is not in the context then a query will be
>   executed and evaluated against the data in the data source, and null
>   is returned if the entity is not found in the context or in the data
>   source.

Usage:

```
public T GetByID(int id)
{
    return _entities.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```